# Create New Column When Characters Not Present

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to create a new column based on values which lack two characters.

```
Column1
a-b
c
d
e:f
```

Needs to become:

```
Column1    Column2
a-b
c          c
d          d
e:f
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to do it with np.where at first, but I need to retain the original values.  I tried to do it with regex, but the values will change per dataset.  I also tried to use str.contains, but couldn't figure out a != equivalent.

Comment: What about `len`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract all alpha by using `extractall`, then we using `str.len()` to get the condition when it is equal to 1

```
df['Column2']=df.Column1.loc[df.Column1.str.extractall('(\w+)').sum(level=[0])[0].str.len()==1]
df
Out[472]: 
  Column1 Column2
0     a-b     NaN
1       c       c
2       d       d
3     e:f     NaN
```

Update : Base on your comment you need `contains`

```
df['Column2']=df.Column1[~df.Column1.str.contains(':|-')]
df
Out[513]: 
  Column1 Column2
0     a-b     NaN
1       c       c
2       d       d
3     e:f     NaN
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however, the value wanted won't always have a len of 1.  It will change per dataset.

Comment: @JustonLantrip But in your question it says "rows which lack 2 characters".... so you should frame your question right.

Comment: Not a length of 2, two specific characters.  - and :